# Finding the residue of essential singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series, singularity

I Was wondering about how you find the residue for an essential singularity. I was under the impression that finding the first non zero term in the principle series of the Laurent series only works for isolated singularities?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Essential singularities are supposed to be isolated singularities, right?! If not, then *how* do you define “isolated singularity”?

Comment: My bad, my question is do you still take the first non zero term in the principle part of the Laurent series for the residue if the principle part of the series is infinite?

Comment: No, review the definition of residue.

Comment: @CW Please read my answer then.

Answer (score 1):

No. By definition, the residue is the coefficient of $\frac1z$ of the Laurent series. For instance, if you have to compute the residue at $0$ of $\sin\left(\frac1z\right)$ you not that$$\sin\left(\frac1z\right)=\frac1z-\frac1{3!z^3}+\cdots$$and so the residue is $1$ (the coefficient of $\frac1z$).

Comment: thank you, so the definition of the residue still applies?

Comment: Yes, it does. But please note that, as you have already been told in the comments to your question, that the definition of residue that you mentions was wrong.